# Carrierwave, Sequel, Sinatra, import throught irb, update

Tags: ruby, sinatra, carrierwave, irb, sequel

This is a two-level issue, hope the first one solves the second one.

1. I'd like to be able to save a new object through a script with something like

   ```
   @file = File.open("/path/to/image.png")
   @user = User.new(:name => "SomeName", :avatar => @file)
   @user.save
   ```

   But sadly, it only responds a

   ```
   #<User @values={:name =>"SomeName"}>
   ```

   so I tried:

   ```
   @user = User.new(:name => "SomeName", :avatar => "/path/to/image.png")
   ```

   but I got:

   ```
   CarrierWave::FormNotMultipart: CarrierWave::FormNotMultipart
   ```

   I need to get the script working because I need import several thousand users :S

   It does work PERFECTLY only when a new User and Avatar get posted via the HTML form, but not upon an update, which takes me to...
2. Once a User exists I cannot change the avatar by simply doing in my controller

   ```
   @user.update(params[:user])
   ```

I guess the problem is  that I am not telling carrierwave all that it needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is old. But still, hope it helps someone:

```
@user.update(params[:user])
@user.save
```

RUN SAVE after the update. That's it!